# How to get id from List in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am trying to get id from the the given list and user it to find all Users and display it
by id, maybe the better way would be to use stream but i am not familiar with stream
could anyone help me please

Here is code below,

```
 List<MessageModel> messageModel = messageService.finAll(user.getId());
    UserModel userModel = userRepository.retrieveUserId(messageModel.getId)));
    model.addAttribute("users", userModel);
```

maybe i am doing something wrong

MessageModel looks like

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class MessageModel {
        private Long id;
        private String text;
        private Long sender_id;
        private User user;
}
```

finally i solve the problem, would like and would like to demonstrate you how i did

```
   List<MessageModel> messageModel = messageService.finAll(user.getId());
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MessageModel messageModel1 : messageModel) {
        Long id = messageModel1.getSender_id();
        list.add(id);
    }
    UserModel userModel = userRepository.retrieveListUserId(list);
```

maybe it is not good solution, but it works.

Comment: Does it work? If yes, the I guess you are doing it correctly.

Comment: No, it is not working

Comment: so yes, you are doing something wrong.  now tell us what is happening? does it even compile?

Comment: Due to the  messageModel is List, it has only get and getClass method and it doen;t compile

Comment: So read the javadocs for `List` and understand what you have to do

Comment: `userRepository.retrieveUserId(messageModel.get(0).getId())));` might work for you.

Comment: thanks to everyone, you can see above how i solved my problem, hope is good solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are on at least Java 8 you can use the map function in Streams. So it would like this:

```
List<Long> list = messageModel.stream().map({ model -> model.id }).(Collectors.toList());
```